Unable to update Entry in MySQL
The HTML/EJS:
<div class="Edit-Panel" style="display: none;">
        <div class="Edit-Wrapper">

            <div class="Editing">
                <p class="Edit-Header">Editing:</p>
                <p class="UserSelected">#usernamehere</p>
            </div>

            <div class="Edit-Inputs">

                <div class="Input-Bar">
                    <input id="Edit-Username" class="Edit-Input" type="text" placeholder="Change Username">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
                </div>

                <div class="Input-Bar">
                    <input id="Edit-Password" class="Edit-Input" type="text" placeholder="Change Password">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-lock"></i>
                </div>

                <div class="Input-Bar">
                    <select name="User-Level" class="Drop-Down" id="Edit-Organization">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Organization</option>
                        <% organizations.forEach(org => { %>
                            <option value="<%= org.organizationID %>"><%= org.organizationName %></option>
                        <% }); %>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="Input-Bar">
                    <select name="Role" class="Drop-Down" id="Edit-Role">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Edit Role</option>
                        <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
                        <option value="Teacher">Teacher</option>
                        <option value="Student">Student</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <button class="Edit-Btn" id="Submit-Edit"> Submit Changes </button>
                <button class="Edit-Btn" id="Close-Edit"> Cancel </button>

            </div>


        </div>
    </div> 

Relevant Frontend JS:
const userId = localStorage.getItem('selectedUserId');
const editUsernameInput = document.getElementById('Edit-Username');
const editPasswordInput = document.getElementById('Edit-Password');
const editOrganizationSelect = document.getElementById('Edit-Organization');
const editRoleSelect = document.getElementById('Edit-Role');
const submitEditBtn = document.getElementById('Submit-Edit');

let editedFields = {};

editUsernameInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
    editedFields.username = editUsernameInput.value;
});

editPasswordInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
    editedFields.password = editPasswordInput.value;
});

editOrganizationSelect.addEventListener('change', function () {
    const selectedOption = editOrganizationSelect.options[editOrganizationSelect.selectedIndex];
    editedFields.organizationID = selectedOption.value; 
    console.log('Organization ID:', editedFields.organizationID); 
});


editRoleSelect.addEventListener('change', function () {
    editedFields.role = editRoleSelect.value;
});

submitEditBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log(editedFields.organizationID);
    const requestBody = { userId, ...editedFields };

    fetch('/api/useredit', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            alert('Changes submitted successfully.');
            editedFields = {};
            editUsernameInput.value = '';
            editPasswordInput.value = '';
            editOrganizationSelect.selectedIndex = 0;
            editRoleSelect.selectedIndex = 0;
        } else {
            alert('Error submitting changes.');
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        alert('Error submitting changes:', error);
    });
});

Backend:
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const DBconnection = require('../DB/Connector');

router.post('/useredit', (req, res) => {
    const { userId, username, password, organizationID, role } = req.body;
    console.log('Received Organization ID:', organizationID);

    let updateFields = [];
    let updateValues = [];

    if (username) {
        updateFields.push('UserName = ?');
        updateValues.push(username);
    }
    if (password) {
        updateFields.push('UserPassword = ?');
        updateValues.push(password);
    }
    if (role) {
        updateFields.push('UserRole = ?');
        updateValues.push(role);
    }

    if (updateFields.length === 0) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'No fields to update' });
    }

    updateValues.push(userId);

    const updateUserQuery = `UPDATE useraccounts SET ${updateFields.join(', ')} WHERE UserID = ?`;

    DBconnection.query(updateUserQuery, updateValues, (err, updateUserResult) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Error updating user:", err);
            return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error updating user' });
        }

        if (organizationID) {
            const updateSectionLinkQuery = `UPDATE sectionlinks SET SectionID = ? WHERE UserID = ?`;
            const updateSectionLinkParams = [organizationID, userId];

            DBconnection.query(updateSectionLinkQuery, updateSectionLinkParams, (err, updateSectionLinkResult) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error("Error updating sectionlink:", err);
                    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error updating sectionlink' });
                }

                console.log('Section Link Update Result:', updateSectionLinkResult);

                return res.status(200).json({ message: 'User updated successfully' });
            });
        } else {
            return res.status(200).json({ message: 'User updated successfully' });
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router; 


Why am I getting a POST http://localhost:3000/api/useredit 400 (Bad Request)
Whenever I try to change/update a given users Organization. I am able to change the users, Username, Password, and Role. But when I try to change the Organization I get the Bad Request.
Through The Console Logs I have verified that on the front end the correct Organization ID is being taken and sent to the backend, and the first console log also returns the proper Organization ID is being received.
However all the other logs past

if (organizationID)


Does not return anything and no Changes to the Database occurs.
Any help is appreciated and please don't be too harsh.

Why does changing organizationID not happen in the same part of the code as changing the user's Username, Password, and Role?

@AndrewMorton looks like it's an update to a separate table for the relationship (??)

First thing I would do is look at the actual request that's being POSTed via the browser Network tab

Yes it separate due to the organizationID being in another table.

Mhh since it's a 400 response, did you check what the request body looks like? I mean, there are only 2 possible things happening here: either that one time in your backend code where you set the status to 400 is fired, or the request in itself has issues, like the JSON is in the wrong format or something.

@GreenSaiko on testing i added a log for the request body and got this { userId: '6', organizationID: '17' } Looking at i dont see anything wrong with the request body

Overall I Made Some Changes In How I Approached The Backend Code But Retains Much Of The Previous Code

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const DBconnection = require('../DB/Connector');

router.post('/useredit', (req, res) => {
    const { userId, username, password, organizationID, role } = req.body;
    console.log('Received Request Body:', req.body);

    // Initialize an array to store the promises for each update operation
    const updatePromises = [];

    // Update user details if provided
    if (username || password || role) {
        const updateFields = [];
        const updateValues = [];
        if (username) {
            updateFields.push('UserName = ?');
            updateValues.push(username);
        }
        if (password) {
            updateFields.push('UserPassword = ?');
            updateValues.push(password);
        }
        if (role) {a
            updateFields.push('UserRole = ?');
            updateValues.push(role);
        }

        const updateUserQuery = `UPDATE useraccounts SET ${updateFields.join(', ')} WHERE UserID = ?`;
        const updateUserParams = [...updateValues, userId];
        
        updatePromises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            DBconnection.query(updateUserQuery, updateUserParams, (err, updateUserResult) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error("Error updating user:", err);
                    reject('Error updating user');
                } else {
                    resolve('User details updated successfully');
                }
            });
        }));
    }

    // Update user's organization if provided
    if (organizationID !== undefineda) {
        const updateSectionLinkQuery = `UPDATE sectionlinks SET SectionID = ? WHERE UserID = ?`;
        const updateSectionLinkParams = [organizationID, userId];
        updatePromises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            DBconnection.query(updateSectionLinkQuery, updateSectionLinkParams, (err, updateSectionLinkResult) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error("Error updating sectionlink:", err);
                    reject('Error updating sectionlink');
                } else {
                    resolve('User organization updated successfully');
                }
            });
        }));
    }

    // Execute all update operations asynchronously
    Promise.all(updatePromises)
        .then(messages => {
            res.status(200).json({ messages });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            res.status(500).json({ error });
        });
});

module.exports = router;



